# Which is the first movie to show movie right after production logo without cuts?

Tags: first-appearance, beauty-and-the-beast-2017

While I was watching *Sunshine* (2007), *Rings* (2017) & *Beauty and the Beast* (2017). I noticed that the movie starts right after intro of production logo without any cuts.

For example: *Beauty and the Beast* (2017), we can see movie started with still production logo visible.

[image: the start of the 2017 live action version of Beauty and the Beast]

Answer (score 8):

Raiders of the Lost Ark (1981) starts with the mountain that is shown in the Paramount Logo.

[image]

The other Indiana Jones films use the same technique.

In Temple of Doom (1984) the logo dissolves into an image of a mountain cast in a gong.
[image]

In The Last Crusade (1989) the logo dissolves into a rock formation in the desert.

[image]

In Kingdom of the Crystal Skull (2008) the logo dissolves into an ant hill.

[image]

Obviously, Raiders of the Lost Ark was the first of these films.

Comment: This was a great tradition used through all the Indy films, I believe

Comment: But was it the first movie to do so?

Comment: There are some candidates here, but I don't see any that actually proceed into the action of the film, as opposed to being self-contained gags during the logo:https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LogoJoke